# How can i send a video stream from React js to Python server using getusermedia?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, webrtc

Can anyone guide me about sending a **video stream using getusermedia**, the input is a continuous video stream from a webcam. I can't figure out **how and in which format to send the stream object** into the server for further video analysis.

I am using websocket for the communication and it is working fine, but i am stuck only with this implementation.

**React**

```
const userVideo = useRef();
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/ws')

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
        { audio: false, 
        video: {
            mandatory: { minAspectRatio: 1.333, maxAspectRatio: 1.334}
            }}
    ).then(stream => {
        userVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
```

> **It is Connecting with the python server, but passing uservideo.current.srcobject() is not helping, as i remember it is useful to stream video into another browser.**

```
        socket.onopen = () => socket.send(userVideo.current.srcObject)
        socket.onmessage = function (event) {
         console.log("[message] Data received from server:");
    }          

    }).catch(function(err) {
        //log to console first 
        console.log(err); /* handle the error */
    });
```

So, what could be the possible way to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.